# Trackpad not detected after upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: dell, touchpad, synaptics, 21.10

I have been using Ubuntu with my Dell Precisoon E5470 flawlessly, until I upgraded to version 21.10. The trackpad is simply not detected anymore, e.g. `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` does not list the trackpad. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Fujitsu Lifebook U7410. Booting the old 21.04 kernel (5.11) fixes the problem, but that's no permanent solution. Looks like there's been a change in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `less /proc/bus/input/devices` command to check if kernel is detecting the touchpad on your system.

If it's okey then use `sudo apt update && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Then reboot your system.

Comment: You can also reinstall using `sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: `less /proc/bus/input/devices` and `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` return the same list of devices and no, the kernel is not detecting the trackpad anymore since the update to 21.10. Any further suggestions are welcome!