# I upgrade to Ubuntu 23.10, now, I can't open anything with touchpad to open anything I need to press touchpad button then it works, what can I do?

Tags: 23.10

I was on Ubuntu 23.0.1 something then it ask for upgrade to 23.10 version. After install that I can't open anything or do anything with just click, it doesn't response my clicking on touchpad. To do anything I need to press touchpad button. Why I'm getting this problem?

Comment: Same problem for 23.10: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491432/mantic-minotaur-upgrade-touchpad-stops-working Similar problem for 21.10: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371392/trackpad-not-detected-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-10